# Notion column_list empty columns

Tags: json, api, next.js, notion-api

Building a Nextjs app with Notion as Headless CMS.
When i fetch the blocks, all of them work good except `column_list`, which renders the `column` children but not getting their content.
This is how i render the blocks:

```
export const getBlocks = async (blockId: string) => {
  const blocks = [];
  let cursor;
  while (true) {
    const { results, next_cursor }: any = await notion.blocks.children.list({
      start_cursor: cursor,
      block_id: blockId,
    });
    blocks.push(...results);
    if (!next_cursor) {
      break;
    }
    cursor = next_cursor;
  }
  return blocks;
};
```

... and then in getStaticProps i do this:

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
 
  const { id } = context.params;
 
  const blocks = await getBlocks(id);


  // Retrieve block children for nested blocks (one level deep), for example toggle blocks
  // https://developers.notion.com/docs/working-with-page-content#reading-nested-blocks
  const childBlocks = await Promise.all(
    blocks
      .filter((block: any) => block.has_children)
      .map(async (block: any) => {
        return {
          id: block.id,
          children: await getBlocks(block.id),
        };
      })
  );
  const blocksWithChildren = blocks.map((block: any) => {
    // Add child blocks if the block should contain children but none exists
    if (block.has_children && !block[block.type].children) {
      block[block.type]["children"] = childBlocks.find(
        (x: any) => x.id === block.id
      )?.children;
    }
    return block;
  });

  return {
    props: {
     
      blocks: blocksWithChildren,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};
```

...so when i `console.log("BLOCKSSS", blocks);` i get this:

[image]

As you see the `column:{}` is empty even thought i have content on those 2 columns:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!